# Format SCSS/CSS/LESS with Prettier with rules of Stylelint

Tags: css, sass, less, prettier, stylelint

Right now, I'm trying to format my SCSS code with Prettier, with the rules of Stylelint. I'm having a hard time getting these two to line up.

For example, I keep getting `declaration-colon-new-line` error with stylelint (which is correct) for the following scss code:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50%, #263b59 50%),
    linear-gradient(135deg, #263b59 50%, transparent 50%),
    radial-gradient(transparent 0%, transparent 0%);
```

It *should* look like the following (or something to satisfy the rule) after being formatted with Prettier, but I cannot find the options or how to do so:

```
background-image: 
    linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50%, #263b59 50%),
    linear-gradient(135deg, #263b59 50%, transparent 50%),
    radial-gradient(transparent 0%, transparent 0%);
```

Can anyone please help me get Prettier to auto-format things with the rules of Stylelint? I'm very new to this so a little lost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [integrate Prettier with stylelint](https://prettier.io/docs/en/integrating-with-linters.html) by turning off the conflicting stylelint rules using the [stylelint-config-prettier shared config](https://github.com/prettier/stylelint-config-prettier).

For example:

```
// .stylelintrc
{
  "extends": [
    "stylelint-config-standard" // or whatever config you're using
    "stylelint-config-prettier"
  ]
}
```

Prettier will then be responsible for the bulk of the formatting, and stylelint will be responsible for [checking for possible errors](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/list#possible-errors) and [limiting languages features](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/list#limit-language-features).

Comment: This definitely does the job, but I would prefer the new-lines to happen when needed. I feel like I need to cancel format on save and format manually :(

Comment: Prettier is an opinionated formatter (https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html). If you're using Prettier, I suggest embracing however it formats your CSS. If you'd prefer more control, then I suggest not using Prettier for your CSS and using stylelint to fix any stylistic issues, as it has a large set of configuration options.

Comment: Stylelint is very much supported. There's was a major release (14.0.0) on Oct 21 2021 that was the accumulation of 8 months of work. New releases are put out regularly: https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/releases

Comment: As of Stylelint v15 all style-related rules have been deprecated. If you are using v15 or higher and are not making use of these deprecated rules, this plugin is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to all of this, but might be able to help.  I have been working on getting stylelint to autofix on save for just CSS.  I have a .stylelintrc file in my project folder with all of my rules.  The settings.json to stop Prettier from overriding:

```
{
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "[css]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": null,
        "editor.formatOnSave": false
    },
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "prettier.useTabs": true,
    "prettier.proseWrap": "never",
    "prettier.printWidth": 300,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll.stylelint": true
    }
}
```

Its working for me so far!

Comment: `"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {"source.fixAll.stylelint": true}`
this made the whole difference, thanks a lot!